# Prestashop Friendly URL rules

Tags: url-rewriting, prestashop-1.6, friendly-url

How could I write the rules to convert those links to the friendly ones after the , the produced friendly URL below show broken links

This URL 
http://www.elektrojo.com/index.php?id_post=2&fc=module&module=nextblog&controller=nbpost
To this friendly one
 http://www.elektrojo.com/blog/2-second-blog

Also These

http://www.elektrojo.com/index.php?fc=module&module=nextblog&controller=nblog

> > > http://www.elektrojo.com/blog

http://www.elektrojo.com/index.php?id_collection=1&fc=module&module=nextblog&controller=nbcollection

> > > http://www.elektrojo.com/blog/collection/1-test

http://www.elektrojo.com/index.php?year=2016&month=5&fc=module&module=nextblog&controller=nbarchive

> > > http://www.elektrojo.com/blog/archive/2016-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an empty directory "/blog" in root of your domain just remove or rename that empty directory and friendly link to blog will start working